# APA 6 class: Individual title page instead of \maketitle

Tags: titles, apa6

I am writing my master thesis using the `APA 6` Class. I would like to use a PDF as a title page that I got from my university. I can read it in with `\includpdf`, but if I do this and remove the `\maketitle` command in my file, the abstract wouldn't compile. Do you have an idea of how to get rid of the "official" title page for the `APA 6` Class, use my own title page with `\includpdf`, followed by my abstract? Or is there another way to get the same results?

Here is an MWE for the whole thesis:

```
 \input{02-preambel}
\begin{document}
% \includepdf{Deckblatt}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\input{03-EinleitungForschungshintergrund}
\input{04-FragestellungHypothesen}
\input{05-Methode}
\input{06-Ergebnisse}
\input{07-Diskussion}
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

And the relevant information in my preambel:

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Shorttitle}
\author{Author Name}
\affiliation{University}
\abstract{\input{Abstract}}
\keywords{Keywords}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\maketitle` removing everything before the typesetting of the abstract.

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Shorttitle}
\author{Author Name}
\affiliation{University}
\abstract{Whatever goes in the abstract}
\keywords{Keywords}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \fussy
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{%
    \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}% BDB
    \noindent\@abstract\par% BDB
    \@ifundefined{@keywords}{}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}% BDB
      \indent\textit{\keywordname:} \@keywords%
    }%
    \newpage
  }
  \@ifundefined{def@donotrepeattitle}{
    \section{\protect\normalfont{\@title}}
  }{}%
  \raggedright%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf{example-image-9x16}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]